# Fullcalendar does not Re-render Events when calendar is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I am trying to update my calendar (fullcalendar.js) dynamically, however it is not rerendering the events when the calendar is not visible. I'm also using javascript tabs in my web app so by 'not visible' I mean that it is on a different tab. I've set up a jsfiddle to demonstrate the behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/35kU5/10/

If you click the **Add** button while you are on the tab that contains the calendar, the events will be added and immediately visible.

However, if you click the **Add** button while you are on the second (empty) tab, then switch back to the first tab with the calendar, the 'added' events are not there until you force the calendar to repaint them by some action such as switching the view from *week* to *month*, or switching days/weeks/months, then going back.

I've tried the

```
$("#calendar").fullcalendar('refetchEvents');
$("#calendar").fullcalendar('rerenderEvents');
```

methods, neither of these solve the issue....Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Or is this simply not possible?

Comment: Did u noticed that calendar got duplicated whenever u click add button in tab *One* and as well as in tab *Two*? Because u r trying to create events inside onClick function of the button. I think it's not correct way of creating the events for the Calendar.

Comment: I had no other option than to create the new events on click. in my app i load new events to the database, then refetch, obviously you cant do that with jsfiddle, without having a live sandbox setup, which i dont

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Adam Shaw's full calendar selectable demo. It shows that new events will be added by selecting the date.

The full calendar starts with this code which includes the select event. I use ColdFusion and this is how I retrieve data from my database server:

```
        $myCalendar = $('#myCalendar').fullCalendar({
             header: {
             left: 'prev,next today',
             center: 'title',
             right: ''
             },
         theme: true,
         selectable: true,
         selectHelper: true,
         height: 500,
     events:'events.cfc?method=getevents',
         select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        alert('select function chosen');
        // set the dialog date to the date selected on the calendar
        // commented out the dates below when we changed to datetimepicker
   //           $('#eventStart').val(start);
   //           $('#eventEnd').val(end);
  //           added the info below to support the datetimepicker
        $('#eventStart').datetimepicker("setDate", new Date(start));
        $('#eventEnd').datetimepicker("setDate", new Date(end));
        //clear out the contents of the event title and the event id
        $('#eventTitle').val('');
        $('#ID').val('');
        //default the value of all day to halfday value 1, 
                     all day is valued at 2
        $('#eventallday').val(1);
        $('#calEventDialog').dialog('open');
    },...........
```

Here is the code I use for the select function. This is placed at the bottom of my js code.  I reference additional fields you may not use.

```
        var title = $('#eventTitle');
        var start = $('#eventStart');
        var end = $('#eventEnd');
        $('#calEventDialog').dialog({
           resizable: false,
           autoOpen: false,
           title: 'Add Event',
           width: 400,
        buttons: {
            Save: function() {
               if ($('input:radio[name=allday]:checked').val() == "1") {
                    eventClass = "gbcs-halfday-event";
                    color = "#9E6320";
                    end.val(start.val());
                }
              else {
                eventClass = "gbcs-allday-event";
                color = "#875DA8";
            }
            if (title.val() !== '') {
                $myCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                    title: title.val(),
                    start: start.val(),
                    end: end.val(),
                    allDay: true,
                    className: eventClass,
                    color: color
                }, true // make the event "stick"
                );
        $('calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {

         title: ($("#eventTitle").val()),
                    start: ($("#eventStart").val()),
                    end:($("#eventEnd").val()),
        allDay: ($("#allday").val()),
                    color:($("background-Color").val())
                }, true // make the event "stick" 
                );
        $.ajax({
        url: 'events.cfc?method=add_events',
        data: 'title='+ ($("#eventTitle").val())+
                        '&start='+ ($("#eventStart").val()) +'
                         &end='+ ($("#eventEnd").val()) +
            '&id='+ 0 ,
            type: "POST",
         success: function(json) {
         alert('Updated Successfully');


            }
                 })
            }
            $myCalendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
   });
 });// JavaScript Document
```

I hope this points you in the right direction. Thanks for posting your question. You showed me how to use tabs!.